# Is it true that $3$ is the only prime of the form $n^2-1$?

Tags: proof-verification

One less than a perfect square is prime if and only if the prime is 3. Is this really, really true and do we have proof?

Comment: Seeing that a restatement of Legendre's conjecture can be made based on the answer to this question, why is it on hold?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hint: $n^2-1=(n-1)(n+1)$

Should be obvious enough.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain of this?

Comment: Expand the brackets on the right hand side if you have trouble believing this.

Comment: n^2+1n-1n-1 Is this right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: n^2-1 Is this right?

Comment: So n^2-1=n^2-1.

Comment: Yep, as the equation suggests, $(n-1)(n+1)$ is another way of writing $n^2-1$.

Comment: Is it because n squared minus one factors when n>2?

Comment: This factorisation is true for any real number. The point is that $n^2-1$ has two factors $(n-1)$ and $(n+1)$, so it is prime iff either $(n-1)$ or $(n+1)$ is $1$.

Comment: @fixedp the case $n+1=1$ implies $n=0$, which is not prime

Answer (score 4):

Yes. In general, we may factor
$$n^2 - 1 = (n + 1) (n - 1),$$
and both factors are larger that $1$ provided $n > 2$, or equivalently, that $n^2 - 1 > 3$.