# How do you prove that $n^2-1$ is composite when $n>2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, proof-explanation

When $n=2$ we know that  $n^2-1$ is prime but is this the case, when $n>2$?

Comment: Difference of two squares?

Comment: $n^2 - 1 = (n-1)(n+1)$

Comment: And also a duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/949192/11619). Closed as well. Hmm...

Comment: But, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1552283/11619) has survived!

Comment: A veteran tip. Use [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24n%5E2-1%24%2C%20prime&p=2#)!

Comment: Voting on the question was perhaps a bit harsh (closing was inevitable). Not much I can do about that, sorry.

Comment: Sorry that I wasted your time!

Comment: Business as usual :-) Don't worry about it. Better luck with the next question. Do check out [the local guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619)! And try to search!

Comment: Thank you. I will

Answer (score 0):

HINT: $$n^2-1=(n-1)(n+1)$$ so it can not be prime

Comment: Thank you! I was so stupid! I should have noticed that factoring formula. Sorry that I wasted your time.